# Why can't I export MySQL table values as a CSV file in this Codeigniter application?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have been developing a blogging application with CodeIgniter 3.1.8 and Twig.

The application has a *newsletter subscription* system. I make use of a table named *newsletter* with 3 columns: `id`, `email` and `subscription_date`.

In the class **Subscribers** controller, I have created an `export()` method intend to export subscribers as a CSV file:

```
public function export(){
    $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
    $subscribers = $this->Newsletter_model->fetchSubscribers();

    $file_name = 'subscribers_'.date('Ymd').'.csv'; 
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name"); 
        header("Content-Type: application/csv;");


    // CSV creation 
    $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    $header = array("Email", "Subscription Date"); 
    fputcsv($file, $header);
    foreach ($subscribers as $key => $value) { 
        fputcsv($file, $value); 
    }
    fclose($file); 
    redirect('dashboard/subscribers'); 
}
```

In the **Newsletter_model** model:

```
public function fetchSubscribers() {
    $this->db->select('email, subscription_date');
    $this->db->order_by('newsletter.id', 'DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get('newsletter');
    return $query->result();
}
```

The export **form**:

```
<?php echo form_open(base_url('dashboard/subscribers/export'),  ['class' => 'ml-auto']); ?>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="fa fa-file mr-1"></i> Export CSV</button>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

#### The problem

For a reason I have not been able to figure out, *only the table headers are exported*, not the values (emails and dates).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's what I found by replicating your code to a fresh install of Codeigniter.

1. Created a "files" directory on project root
2. I've autoloaded the "database" library and the "url" helper;
3. Created a newsletter table, as described by you, using mockaroo;
4. I'm not considering the request headers, download or redirect, as they didn't seemed wrong to me

- Nothing was changed on the Newsletter_model, just on the controller.

Here's my export()

```
$header = array("Email", "Subscription Date");
$subscribers = $this->newsletter->fetchSubscribers();

$file_name = 'subscribers_'.date('Ymd').'.csv'; 
$file = fopen(BASEPATH . '../files/' . $file_name, 'w');

fputcsv($file, $header);
foreach ($subscribers as $row) {
    fputcsv($file, [$row->email, $row->subscription_date]);
}

fclose($file);
```

What happened is:

1. Your model returns an Array with objects. So, your $row will be a object.
2. fputcsv expects an Array as a second parameter, just like you did with the $header

I think this will work for you. :)

Comment: It does the same thing: values are not present in the CSV, only columns.

Comment: Are you sure? I generated a thoudand random emails and the CSV on the "files" directory was generated correctly. Have you implemented what i have sended?

Comment: This is my copy of the project (with the SQL table) >> https://wetransfer.com/downloads/09224520aefa2ae9415cba3a9df3492820210320211022/1fdfe3

Comment: The code there is the code that doesn't work. Check the wetransfer i've sended and test it on your project.